# Async methods in C# configuring splash screen controls

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, splash-screen

I'm trying to show and manage a splashscreen over async methods but don't really know how to manage this. These are my methods:

```
    public async void OpenSplashScrn()
    {
        splash.Show();
    }

    public async void ChangeSplashScrnMessageText(string messageText)
    {
        splash.messageLabel.Content = messageText;
    }

    public void HideSplashScrn()
    {
        splash.Hide();
    }
```

I tried it with await but don't know how to invoke that correctly. Starting the splashscreen does work but the Labeltext does not Change when calling the other method. I also want to call the methods in an order like: open,change text (a couple of times), hide, open,change text(a couple of times), hide. I didn't find a solution for this concrete problem.
Thank you!

EDIT:

Seems that this is no Async problem. A Little bit more code when calling the functions:

```
        splash = new SplashScreen(this);
        OpenSplashScrn();
        ChangeSplashScrnMessageText("Searching Data...");
```

Xaml Code for the splashscreen:

```
 <Window x:Name="splashScrn" x:Class="Window1.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Bitte warten..." Height="127" Width="336" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="True">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,2" Background="#FF386C89">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="254*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="messageLabel" Content="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Those async-modifiers are redundant since there is no async code withing those voids.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `splash.Show` and not `splash.ShowDialog` your splash screen will be non-modal. If that is what you want, you don't need to use any `async` methods.
By using `Show` the control flow of your application is kept in the calling window.

So the methods shown should actually work (except that the `async` modifiers have no effect at all, since there is no `await`). As to why your label text does not change, you will need to debug this. Is the line

```
splash.messageLabel.Content = messageText;
```

really called with correct values?

Comment: I want a splashscreen, so I should invoke it with .Show(). Yes it is called with correct values but the labeltext does not change.

Comment: No. Even then nothing changes. Why is this so?

Comment: I guess I should make this async to call the controls from my main window or not?

Comment: When I'm trying to put properties into the splashscreen class then the getter tells me that he can not convert string to object. It works for you? Are you doing something else then me? :(

Comment: @Jackson30 No I'm just setting the `Content` of the label with a string. We cannot solve this in these comments, please update your question if you have new information.